# What is the difference between those 2 filter?

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, range

here I have 2 time range filter, the first one is:

```filter1:

```
{
  "range": {
    "end": {
      "gt": "now"
    }
  }
},
{
  "range": {
    "start": {
      "lte": "now"
    }
  }
}
```

```
and the second one is:

```filter2:

```
{
  "range": {
    "end": {
      "gt": "now"
    },
    "start": {
      "lte": "now"
    }
  }
}
```

```

and I have a doc which is:

```doc

```
{
  "start": "now-8m",
  "end": "now+8m"
}
```

```

### Here is the question, where filter1 works but filter2 doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second filter doesn't work because the syntax is not correct.

The `range` query only supports a single field. If you want to compare two different fields, you need two different `range` queries.